# What version of GCC is used by the make command?

Tags: gcc, make

Is there any way to know what version of gcc is used by the `make` command? I have 5 versions installed of gcc on my computer:
by `dpkg -l | grep gcc`

```
ii  gcc                                                   4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6                                    i386         GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.6                                               4.6.4-6ubuntu2                                      i386         GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.6-base:i386                                     4.6.4-6ubuntu2                                      i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.8                                               4.8.2-19ubuntu1                                     i386         GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.8-base:i386                                     4.8.2-19ubuntu1                                     i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.9-base:i386                                     4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1                               i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc-4.8-dev:i386                                   4.8.2-19ubuntu1                                     i386         GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1:i386                                          1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1                             i386         GCC support library
```

Comment: @karel 1. Its a duplicate on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu/9103299), 2. I think that its a generic programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
gcc --version
```

If that's not the version of gcc you want you can change the default gcc version using the `update-alternatives` command to determine which actual file is referenced by a generic name, for example which actual file is referenced by `gcc`. For more information see the answers to this question: [How to change the default GCC compiler in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu).

Comment: how to make sure which [make] use this one

Comment: @lion karel is telling you, the default version (printed with the command above) is used by `make`

Comment: +1  ok but how to make sure |: D;

Comment: You can also explicitly switch from the default version of gcc (aka "auto mode") to a different version of gcc temporarily (manual mode) by following the instructions in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu/9103299#9103299).

Comment: on meta I requested to migrate that link to here.

Comment: @lion: Why migrate? It properly belongs on StackOverflow. `make` and `gcc` are not specific to Ubuntu, far from that.

Comment: yes I ask that on meta and I got the answer. nice to see their answer http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11540/please-migrate-this-question

Comment: You may also need to check the makefile, some explicitly state a version.

Answer (score 5):

Makefiles often use implicit rules to compile things, rather than defining the compiler specifically. In this case, the convention (and default) is to use `$(CC)`, which defaults to `cc`. So if you type `cc --version`, you'll see what Makefiles use by default.

The Makefile may override the definition of `CC` though, or not use `$(CC)` at all. But is the convention (as it is within autoconf for `configure` scripts, too).

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969222/make-gnu-make-use-a-different-compiler

Answer (score 3):

`make` only does whatever the Makefile tells it to do. Most Makefiles will use the default `gcc` command, so karel's answer applies in most cases, but you should be aware that there's nothing that forces `make` to use the default GCC. (And for that matter, `make` can be used for a lot of things besides compiling C, so it might not even use GCC at all.)